# How to deactivate Tooltips in CefSharp (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I'm programming a WPF application (.NET 4.8) with CefSharp (95.7) as the browser component.
I would like to deactivate the tooltips which show up when hovering over a link which has a title but I cannot find any setting in the current API, neither could I find anything when searching StackOverflow nor the web.

Comment: This is an unusual request and as such there is no setting. Potentially you can override the dependency property metadata. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/96/CefSharp.Wpf/ChromiumWebBrowser.cs#L1518

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I will investigate this!